# Dynamically load a jar

Tags: java, jar, classloader

My application needs some components (jar files) to be loaded/unloaded dynamically on request. For example, I have abc.jar and xyz.jar and on demand my application should be able to load/unload  abc.jar or xyz.jar or replace these jars with different versions of jars. Are there any approaches to load/unload jar files dynamically (i.e. without restarting the server)?

While reading in net I got few ideas about osgi, but I don't want to go into framework which may make complex. Is there are simple approach to achieve this? I am using Java, J2EE and Jetty 6 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the seminal paper "[Dynamic class loading in the Java virtual machine](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=286945)", by Bracha and Liang. They explain how class loaders work, and how you can use interfaces and class loader to support dynamic changes. It's a worthy read (you should be able to obtain a free PDF by googling the name of the paper) !

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Shared Library and Refer the same in your application Server Class/Library path.

And you can change the versions of the jars you place in them whenever you want.